# Adding extensionattribute to ADobject includes more info than it should

Tags: powershell, active-directory

```
$CSV = Import-Csv -Delimiter "," -Header username,Phone -Path "C:\Tempo\info.csv"
foreach ($username in $CSV) {
    $Temp = "$username.Phone"
    Set-ADuser -Identity $username.Username -Add @{extensionAttribute4="$Temp"}
}
```

With the CSV file looking like this (one row)

```
Jakob.User, 6789
```

When running above Code it adds the following value to the AD object:

> @{username=Jakob.User; Phone=6789}.Phone

Instead of what I except, which would be 6789.

Is it something in my code or is more of a "serverfault" (or just how it is excepted to run?)

But if i modify the code so it is `Add @{extensionAttribute4="aFineExample"}`
 and then go look at the value, it only adds what i except it to add.

Comment: I dont see how that is relevant to my issue,  My issue is more that when i except it to enter "6789" it enters "@{username=Jakob.User; Phone=6789}.Phone" instead

Comment: It's relevant in the sense that you are experiencing that exact problem, and the answer(s) there will solve it. You're trying to embed a property of an object in a string and you're doing it incorrectly; which is why your value ends in `.Phone`.

Comment: Okay, I'll read up on it then.

Comment: @briantist It solved it! Thanks :)